# Echoing Elementor page content in template, but it doesn't get styles and some widgets are missing

Tags: templates

I built a page with Elementor, and I want to use it as my home page. When I use a static home page with my theme, it still gets wrapped with the header, footer, and content container, which I don't want in this case.

I've built a simple `front-page.php` template to try to just output the contents of this page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js no-svg">
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>

    <body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php
$page = get_page_by_path( 'home' );
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content); 
echo $content;

get_footer();
?>
  </body>

  <?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

This works to output the *content*, but I don't get the styles and my posts widgets are MIA. How can I modify this template to also get the styles and so that all the widgets will be present?

Comment: In your theme, are the styles actually enqueued through `functions.php`? Since you have `wp_head()` here they should come through if they are. If not, you should remove them from being directly added to `header.php` and instead enqueue, so they can also appear here. As far as widgets, it depends on where your widgetized area is. Check your other template files and see - there is probably a sidebar (even if visually it's not a sidebar, WP calls it a sidebar) which you'll need to call in order to display widgets here as well.

Comment: @WebElaine I'll check where the styles are enqueue. Thanks!
On the widgets, I wasn't at all clear about what I was talking about. I'm referring to an Elementor widget rather than a WordPress widget here. I have a posts list on the page using [Elementor's posts widget](https://docs.elementor.com/article/101-posts)

Comment: @WebElaine I can't find exactly where the styles are enqueued in `functions.php` (although I'm not entirely sure what I'm looking for). What I _can_ say is that they don't appear to be coming in through the `header.php`. I can't see any reference to them at all there. That file also calls `wp_head`, so I assume that's how they're getting in.

Comment: Search your theme files for `style.css` to figure out where it's coming from. If it's added properly you should see a call to `wp_enqueue_style` in `functions.php`. If it's just hard-coded as a `<link rel="stylesheet">` somewhere, that's the problem with the styles. It's also worth inspecting the homepage itself to see whether there is any reference to the styles - it could be the stylesheet is loading but somehow you're missing a body class or something critical. Or could be the stylesheet tries to load but it's the wrong path.

Comment: @WebElaine It looks like it isn't hard-coded as a link. I did find the problem, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. Elementor's post-specific styles are not being delivered with the front page. When I preview the page, there's a stylesheet at `/wp-content/uploads/elementor/css/post-1036.css`. That stylesheet isn't in the sources when I load the home page.
I'm still not clear why my posts Elementor widgets are not showing up though. They aren't even in the markup that's being delivered for the home page.

Comment: Sounds like you need to contact Elementor's authors to figure out the best way to meet your goals.

Comment: You can change the elementor style output to be an inline in the elementor settings->advanced

Comment: @Shibi I’d like to avoid doing it that way if I can, but that will be a good fallback if I can’t find a solution to deliver the page stylesheet. Thanks!

Comment: did you find any specific solution for this problem?

Answer (score 9):

Here is the way,

```
$contentElementor = "";

if (class_exists("\\Elementor\\Plugin")) {
    $post_ID = 124;
    $pluginElementor = \Elementor\Plugin::instance();
    $contentElementor = $pluginElementor->frontend->get_builder_content($post_ID);
}

echo $contentElementor;
```

Answer (score 1):

`get_builder_content` is an internal method, please use `get_builder_content_for_display()`.

```
$frontend = new \Elementor\Frontend();
$page_id  = 100;

echo $frontend->get_builder_content_for_display( $page_id, $with_css = true );
```

Comment: Thank you, I created a shortcode and also theme templates with this very code and works great!

Comment: for me `get_builder_content_for_display` doesn't output anything but `get_builder_content` works fine.