# Why is the current page loaded in the pop-up window and not the specified one?

Tags: php, functions, shortcode

I made a shortcode which I put in the popup. The shortcode just needs to get the content of the page by ID I created in Elementor and show it in a popup with the same design as it is on the inner page.

```
$content_post = get_post(1000);
return do_shortcode( apply_filters( 'the_content', $content_post->post_content ) );
```

Using this code, the current page is loaded into the popup, not with ID 1000 with markup and styles.

If I use code without a filter:

```
return do_shortcode( $content_post->post_content );
```

I am getting content from the page I want, but it is without design from html markup.

Why is this so?
How do I load the page I want into the popup with all the markup and styles I have configured in Elementor?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I was too hasty with the question.
Luckily I found the answer to my question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/370754/161308).